# dotnet core 3.0 WebApi, applicationPart and authorization

Tags: c#, .net-core

We have a modular application, which means that our api controllers get loaded during startup. We load the controllers into the applicationPart like this:

```
services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
            .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(applicationPartManager =>
            {
                foreach (var module in _modules)
                {
                    var apiControllerAssemblies = module.GetApiControllerAssemblies();

                    foreach (var apiControllerAssembly in apiControllerAssemblies)
                        applicationPartManager.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(apiControllerAssembly));
                }
            });
```

We want to protect our apis with Basic authentication. I've created a middleware like this:

```
 public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
    {
        public BasicAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, 
                                          ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
        }

        protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Missing Authorization 
                                                Header");
            //More to come
        }
    }
```

The middleware is registered in startup.cs like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Basic")
             .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("Basic", null);
```

Accessing localhost: will always trigger the `HandleAuthenticateAsync` method. However when I try to access the localhost:/user/users endpoint the method never hit the breakpoint and will always result in a HTTP 401 Unauthorized. The controller itself is marked with the `Authorize` attribute.

Any ideas where it goes wrong? Any hints to where I should start looking for a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Tobias - did you solve your problem and did you find a better way to go about implementing Authentication in .Net Core. I'm starting a new project and was wondering if you've found a better way of doing this.

Comment: HI @Rakesh ended up by creating an Attribute with a filter implementing `IAuthorizationFilter`

Comment: Thanks @Tobias, will try that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but when I had to implement Authentication this is what I did.

a. Declare a class extending `AuthenticationSchemeOptions`

```
    public class CustomAuthOptions: AuthenticationSchemeOptions
    {
    }
```

b. Declare a class implementing the `AuthenticationHandler<TOptions>`

```
    internal class CustomAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<CustomAuthOptions>
    {
        IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        IUser _user;

        public CustomAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<CustomAuthOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock, 
            IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IUser user) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _user = user;
        }

        protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            //logic to authenticate
        }

        protected override Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
        {
            //more code
        }
   }
```

c. Add an extension method to the `AuthenticationBuilder` class

```
        public static AuthenticationBuilder AddCustomAuth(this AuthenticationBuilder builder,
            Action<CustomAuthOptions> config)
        {
            return builder.AddScheme<CustomAuthOptions, CustomAuthHandler>("CheckInDB", "CheckInDB", config);
        }
```

d. Finally in the `Startup.cs`

```
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "CheckInDB";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "CheckInDB";
            }).AddCustomAuth(c => { });
```

This may be more than what is needed, but when I was in the same boat, a couple of months ago, I spent a good few days piecing all of this together.